# How does this phenomenon originate?

Tags: interstellar

In *Interstellar*, the *Endurance*

> passes through a wormhole into another galaxy.

Professor Brand explains that

> gravitational disturbances

have been detected for a number of years before Cooper and Murph use them to find the

> NASA bunker, and I'm assuming that these disturbances were created by Cooper trying to communicate with Murph when he is in the 'extradimensional spacetime structure' (description lifted from the TVTropes page). Did Cooper also create the wormhole for the *Endurance* to fly through? If not, where does it come from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, as Cooper says in the tesseract,

> some future super-advanced descendants of humans made the wormhole.

They're higher-dimension beings who are able to traverse time just as easily as space.  They built the wormhole at a time and place that humans would be able to make use of it to try and find a new home planet.

Comment: Ah, missed that. Thanks.

Comment: .. making it a paradox of sorts, but never mind.